# jQuery change value on radio when I click browser back button

Tags: jquery

I have 2 radio buttons.

I choose the second radio button and submit the form.   Then I click on the browser ”back” button and the first radio button is checked. I want the second button as I choosed to be checked.

How to change this? :)

Pls help a student.

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
  
   var $divs = $('#divs > div');
   
   $divs.first().show();
   
   $('input[type=radio]').on('change',function() {
    
     $divs.hide();
     
     $divs.eq( $('input[type=radio]').index( this ) ).show();
     
   });
 });
```

```html
$html .= '<div class="all-donations-wrapper">';
    $html .= '<h2>'.$section_title.'</h2>';
    $html .= '<div class="gift-type">';
     $html .= '<h4>Gift type:</h4>';
     $html .= '<input id="id_radio2" type="radio" name="name_radio" value="value_radio2" checked="checked"/>';
     $html .= '<label for="id_radio2">'.$donation_title_one_time.'</label>';
     $html .= '<input id="id_radio1" type="radio" name="name_radio" value="value_radio1"/> ';
     $html .= '<label for="id_radio1">'.$donation_title_monthly.'</label>';
    $html .='</div>';

    $html .= '<div id="divs">';
```

Comment: when you click "back" you reload the page. The html you have in your page says that the first option is checked. that's why you get this result

Comment: I removed checked but I still got the same problem when I go back "refresh" hmm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.

The browser back button, by design, takes you to the last web page you accessed - and does not fully preserve the last-known state of the DOM. And most users understand this.

Your best bet is to create your own navigation for your page - your own "Back" button.

You will be banging your head against the wall if you try to reprogram the back button. Also note that you cannot do anything about: (a) the user navigating away from your page, and then returning; (b) Right-Clicking on the page and choosing "BACK" (different from back button); (c) Clicking a bookmark; (d) Typing in the address bar; (e) Right-clicking back button and choosing a site further back in browser's history.

HOWEVER, you can *disable* the back button, forcing users to use your own fully-managed back button, via this code:

```
history.pushState(null, null, location.href);
window.onpopstate = function () {
    history.go(1);
};
```

Reference:

https://codepen.io/dhavalt10/pen/rGLBzB

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/696526/Solution-to-Browser-Back-Button-Click-Event-Handli

https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/when-back-button-clicked-redirect-to-url/224503/5

Comment: "And most users understand this." - Is that necessary?

Comment: When I was a new coder, I thought it necessary to handle use cases that just didn't matter. Senior coders had to point out to me that I was over-engineering, or missing the point in certain areas. Over time, I realized they were right - and that realization would have taken longer without their input. So, yes, I think it's important to help new coders with their focus and to remind them not to redesign the browsers while designing their app.

Comment: No, I agree. I am pointing out that it is not always "what you are saying" so much as "how you say it". I think that point is completely relevant, but you said it in one of the most passive aggressive, non constructive ways possible. Just my two cents. Others may completely disagree with my take and be on your side.

Comment: Certainly not how it was intended - and you are correct that we often don't hear our own voice when writing, esp. when pounding out a quick answer in the 5-mins allotted. How would you re-phrase it?

Comment: So instead of "And most users understand this", I might reword it as, "This is an important and fundamental part of browser behavior that one should make sure they understand when basing design off of it." Something to that effect.

Comment: @Asyranok - Thanks very much. I appreciate your thoughtful input and insights. Let me mull it over and consider how best to integrate your wording. Very kind of you.